# On the existence of the linear operator $T^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X=C[0,1]$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of the continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ whith $\|f\|=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$ for all $f\in X$. Prove that the linear operator 
$$T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1],$$
defined by $(T(f))(t):=t\int_0^tf(s)ds$, $t\in[0,1]$, has a inverse $T^{-1}:Im(T)\to X$. Is it $T^{-1}$ bounded?

I've showed that $\|T\|=1$ and to ensure the existence of $T^{-1}$ I tried to show that $T$ in injective but I could not.
I accept suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have this right? This function is very much not invertible in any reasonable sense.

Comment: Does $[a,b]=[0,1]$?

Comment: There were typos. Now it is right.

Comment: There we go :) that makes sense now!

Comment: The inverse involves dividing by $t$, then taking a derivative. This should help.

Comment: But $t\in[0,1]$. Maybe it will not work  'dividing by $t$'. Am I wrong?

Comment: The inverse needs to be defined only on the image of the operator, so when you are dividing by $t\mapsto t$, you are sure that you have a multiple of that function in the first place. The question (for injectivity, and thus the existence of an inverse on the image space) is whether the quotient is _unique_. The only way two quotients could differ is in their value at $0$; however that value is determined by the continuity requirement from values in the neighbourhood.

Comment: I think you need the hypothesis that $f(x)\ge 0,\forall x\in [0,1]$. Because when you work on proving that T is injective you're going to get to have $\int_0^1 f(s)ds=0$